# Firebase Analytics Debug View for Flutter WEB?

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics, flutter-web

I'm trying to set up Firebase Analytics Debug View for Flutter Web.

I have read the documentation provided, and it says:

> To enable Analytics Debug mode in your browser, install the Google Analytics Debugger Chrome extension.

But since I'm running Flutter Web on VSCode I'm not able to install an extension on that Chrome Web Server.

Since it got installed by default with the Flutter SDK, I don't know how to configure it or where to look for documentation.

Does anyone have an idea of how I could proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use the DebugView with the Chrome extension. If you run Flutter Web as a Web Server, just open your App with Chrome. Be sure the extension is installed and running. Also be sure that Firebase is correctly set up for Web. Then it works!